# Map an error to a vector of errors in Rust's `Result`

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following setup

```rust
fn get_result() -> Result<(), Vec<String>> {
    make_error()?;
    
    Ok(())
}

fn make_error() -> Result<(), String> {
    Err("error".to_string())
}
```

Clearly, this code does not compile because `T != Vec<T>`. The error I get is
`the trait 'From<String>' is not implemented for 'Vec<String>'`. Unfortunately, this error is not actionable, as I can't implement traits external to my crate for types external to my crate.

The solution I have come up with is below, but it is clearly far from elegant. Are there better options?

```rust
trait Vectorize<T, E> {
    fn err_to_vec(self) -> Result<T, Vec<E>>;
}

impl<T, E> Vectorize<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn err_to_vec(self) -> Result<T, Vec<E>> {
        match self {
            Ok(ok) => Ok(ok),
            Err(err) => Err(vec![err])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err):

```
fn get_result() -> Result<(), Vec<String>> {
    make_error().map_err (|e| vec![e])?;
    
    Ok(())
}

fn make_error() -> Result<(), String> {
    Err("error".to_string())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=1a893625ae871feead40d7fdcd53c8f9)

Comment: omg, how could I have missed it? thanks.